# Samsung galaxy note 7 probability problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation

An unnamed smart-phone manufacturer has a problem with their phones bursting into flames.  The phones are shipped to stores in boxes of 12.  Before shipping,  a customer service agent tests 3 of the phones at random to ensure they won't suddenly combust.  If any of the three tested phones shows a sign of possibly burning, the shipment of twelve is held back.  If each phone has an independent probability of 20% that they show a sign of possibly burning, what percentage of shipments is held back?

Comment: How do you test a phone to ensure it won't suddenly combust in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Probability that a phone is good is $0.8$. Probability that three tested phones are good is $0.8^3$ (assuming independence).

$P(\text{ship back})=1-P(\text{all 3 tested phones are good})=1-0.8^{3}= 48.8\%$

Answer (score 0):

So, let $B$ denote "burned" and $N$ denote "non-burned".
We will have 4 possibilites:

$ \{ B, N, N \} $;

$  \{ B, B, N \} $;

$ \{ B,B,B \} $

And finally:

$ \{ N, N, N \} $

You know, from the problem, that $ P(B) = 0,2 $ and $P(A) = 0,8$. Doing one calculation, just as an example:
Probability of the 1st case:
$ P(1st) = 0,2 \cdot 0,8 \cdot 0,8 \cdot 6$
(The $6$ is in there because you have 6 possible ways of this case happen (changing the order of Ns and Bs)
I think this is enough for you to think about the problem and try it. Think about what the problem is asking you, and how can you calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

There are four different possibilities:

- $P(X)$ - First phone fails the test
- $P(Y)$ - Second phone fails the test
- $P(Z)$ - Third phone fails the test
- $P(W)$ - No phone fails the test

As long as $P(W)$ doesn't come to happen, shipment is sent back. So question asks the answer to $1-P(W)$. Since probability of burning is $0.2$ probability of not burning is $0.8$.

$$P(W)=(\frac{8}{10})^{3}$$

$$1-(\frac{8}{10})^{3} = 0.488$$